# Table partitioning vs multiple tables

Tags: sql-server

Say we have a huge table that we run very complex queries on.

Say it's a crm and we have a table called People [id (GUID), listId (Guid), name, email, city, ......]

Would it be better to represent this as multiple tables per user so:

`People_<USER_ID>` and if we have 100 users we have 100 such tables

Or

One table like the above with a user_id column that we partition on?

Comment: How big is "huge"? How frequently do you update the table (inserts/update/delete)? How often do you add "Users"?

Comment: Less than 100 users a day.
Huge is 100 millions so not a huge amount but a huge complexity when it comes to the queries executed in that table. Assume those cannot be simplified further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are advantages and disadvantages to each approach.

For instance, if you use separate tables, you can perform maintenance such as rebuilding indexes or statistics on each individually, and if you add new users, it is simple to create a new table, rather than amending the partition function.

With a partitioned table, queries are vastly simplified, as you won't be relying on a query with a `UNION` for each individual table.

The half-way ground is to use a partitioned view; i.e. build a view that has a definition of the individual tables UNIONed together. This offers some of the advantages of partitioned tables, but the view definition will require maintenance if you add new tables, and with 100 tables, would be quite unwieldy.

Partitioned tables are generally of best use in a data warehouse kind of environment, where you can have a loading table, and add it in as a new partition for each load of data. In this environment, you generally only have data being written to one partition at a defined time, and read from all the partitions the rest of the time.

If your data size is very large, then partitioning could offer some benefits, in terms of the time taken to perform maintenance tasks, if they are only required on one or a few partitions. However, it is best to find a partition function that accommodates this. For example, if your rows are written once and not updated, adding a created datetime and partitioning on that, or using an incrementing primary key and partitioning on that, would mean that you would only need to reindex the active partition.

Comment: I'd also add that both approaches would significantly improve query times where the rows fall into one partition/table. However, partitions are most useful where only a subset of the data is 'active', and by the sounds of it, you would be reading/writing all the partitions. Using partitions over multiple tables may not offer you any benefits other than neatness and the ability to see all your tables in SSMS without wearing out the scroll-bar.

Comment: Let me clarify as I wasn't very clear before. I will ONLY read data from one user partition at a time - so for one user. So I will never end up doing UNIONs and for the odd case (which I can't think of right now) then so be it.

Comment: Partitioning is most useful when you are only generally writing/updating one partition, and all the other partitions are static and essentially read-only. The true advantage of partitions is the ease by which partitions can be 'slid' in and out, only requiring a short schema lock on the table. In contrast, rebuilding an indexed view when its definition changes can be slow and require a lot of space in memory / on disk. If you aren't going to be doing this though, you won't be getting this advantage.

Comment: I see - would you say then that for my case where "partitions" (as data buckets) are constantly very hot, we would benefit more from havign multiple tables?

Comment: I'd say that since you would only be query one table at a time, the advantages of using partitions pretty much melt away (also partitioning is only available in the enterprise versions of SQL Server, which might make setting up a test environment on an express edition trickier). As I said, partitions are really best suited to data warehouse environments with sequential write-once data. It sounds like you have a more random-access type of data, where multiple tables may be the best choice.

Comment: ...The final choice probably depends on the shape of your data, and the way it is accessed (are there reporting requirements over the entire table, or is access ONLY ever on one 'partition' at a time, for instance). Multiple tables will certainly cut down the cost of queries, as long as you know in advance which table your data will be in. Judicious use of indexes on the original table may also give you an appreciable performance benefit, for instance a composite index covering the columns in a where clause, in selectivity order, with returned columns as included columns might surprise you.